# How to locate quota limits for Resource Types per Resource Group?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, quota

Trying to determine what the hard limits of Resources Types are within Resource Groups.

In our instance, we're specifically looking at the Resource Provider *Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses*.

The documentation states "Varies per resource type" but doesn't provide any additional details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits

We are aware that the default limit is 800 resources but would like to know what the hard limit beyond this is.

Also reviewed the Azure Management REST API's and PowerShell Cmdlets but unable to locate any way of pulling this information programmatically.

Comment: if the page doesnt list it (and it says contact support) why dont you contact support (especially because the page says that)? doubt you'd get a right and verifiable answer here (who knows)

Comment: Was advised by Azure Support to post the message here so they could get in contact.

Comment: docs literally say this: `Public IP addresses (dynamic) 5 contact support`

Comment: I guess the first question is, why are you even having an issue with the number of resources in a single resource group? That smells like you should be separating things out in multiple resource groups to better be able to manage them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact support as the article says - SO doesn't have this info.  Support can also adjust the limits for certain resource types.

If you're not getting an answer from support email me: bmoore at msft